# Conectar Wifi a una pycom Lopy4

Tags: python, vscode, wifi

Estoy intentando conectar una pycom Lopy4 a una red wifi. Utilizo visual studio code y python, no me deja hacer el import network.
He visto algún ejemplo de como buscar redes wifi pero no me deja aplicarlo, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te recomendaría que posteares el código en texto, no en imagenes

Answer (score 0):

Para MCU tienes que usar [micropython](http://micropython.org/) que si incluye el modulo `network`.

La forma estándar de conectarse a la red WiFi en micropython es:

```
def WiFi_connect(ssid, password, host_name):
    """ Conecta a la red
    """

    # Operando como cliente de una red WiFi, no como AP.

    station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)

    # Establecer opciones de conexión (usuario, password, hostname).
    station.active(True)
    station.connect(ssid, password)
    # Es conveniente asignarle un nombre a este MCU
    # y poder usarlo para acceder a él desde otro
    # equipo.
    station.config(dhcp_hostname="mynombre")

    # Conectarse
    print("Connecting to WiFi ...")    
    # Hacer 10 intentos maximo
    count = 10
    while not station.isconnected() and count:
        count -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

    if station.isconnected():
        print('Connection successful: %s' % station.config('dhcp_hostname'))
        print(station.ifconfig())
    else:
        print("No WiFi")
```

Te recomiendo instalar [thonny](https://thonny.org/) como IDE (además de/o en lugar de Visual Studio). Es bien básica y de repente medio idiota, pero te permite subir y bajar módulos con relativa facilidad via USB, y te da acceso al REPL en la placa.